# Threads in snake

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I'm making a game like snake. And I have a problem with Start button. When I start everything is working well but if I start the game again with button, a new snake is moving faster, and with every restart using the button it's moving faster then last one. I have no idea what's wrong with code, could somebody explain me my mistake ?

```
// In Frame class
addButton(buttonPanel, "Start", event -> 
    {
        counter = -1; // resets points counting
    area.start();  // area is a JPanel variable in Frame class
    area.snake();           
    });

// In JPanel class
public void start()
{
    body.removeAll(body); // ArrayList with snake body elements
    add();
    body.get(0).setX(300);
    body.get(0).setY(300);
    repaint();
}

public void snake()
{
    Runnable r = () ->
    {
    try {
            while(!isCollided())
            {
                for(int a=body.size()-1; a>0 ;a--) // Moving elements
                {
                    if(a>0)
                    {
                    body.get(a).setX(body.get(a-1).getX());
                    body.get(a).setY(body.get(a-1).getY());
                    }
                }

    body.get(0).move();
    double a = Math.abs(((body.get(0).getCenterX())-(food.getRandX()+5)));
    double b = Math.abs(((body.get(0).getCenterY())-(food.getRandY()+5)));
    if((a<10) && (b<10)) // Eating and growing a snake
    {
    food.newFood();
    add();
    }

    this.repaint();
    Thread.sleep(waiting); // waiting is final int = 100;
        }
            if(isCollided()) return;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { return;}

    };
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: We probably need that button code then. I dont see anything in the above code that seems to deal with "speed" ...

Comment: On each `snake()` invocation you add a new 'mover' `Thread`. But I don't see how you dispose them.

Comment: Try using a debugger

Comment: So, how I can restart game without adding a new mover Thread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like on each `snake()` invocation you create a new thread that moves your snake. I don't see where they are disposed.

One of the ways to solve this is to have only one 'mover' `Thread`. On button press you could reset the field (including the snake).

The trick here is to make sure that your data structure (which represents the snake and the field) does not get modified by two threads at the same time (as you would have a mover thread and a UI thread processing that button click that resets the field).

Synchronization could be used to overcome this difficulty.

```
private final Object monitor = new Object();
```

Then in your mover thread

```
while (!isCollided()) {
    synchronized (monitor) {
        // make all the modifications to the shared data (i.e. the field)
    }
    ...
    Thread.sleep(...);
}
```

And in your 'new game' button click handler:

```
synchronized (monitor) {
    // reset the shared data (the field)
}
```

An important thing is to make sure that the code under `synchronized` works quickly. If your mover thread takes the lock and then works for seconds inside it, then your button click handler will have to wait all those seconds, and your UI will freeze.